# Android navigation clear whole backstack

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I currently have an Android application when in the process of browsing a hierarchy of objects creates a back stack like this.

BrowseActivity(Starting Instance) -> BrowseActivity(Instance B) -> BrowseActivity(Instance C) -> ViewObjectActivity

There is a menu button in the view object activity that I would like to have take the user back to BrowseActivity(Starting Instance) and destroy the rest of the browse activities.

Using Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP only destroys the ViewObjectActivity and leaves the rest in the back stack.

Setting the BrowseActivity to "singleTop" in the manifest breaks the ability to create another instance for further navigation.

Any way to accomplish this that I am probably overlooking?

Comment: This link in the docs might help: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the menu option to take the user back to the first activity, do just that - take the user *back* to the first activity.

Have your third activity exit with a specific result that tells the second activity to exit as well. You can extend this to how many activities you want - as long as all the activities except the first one exit, you're good.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this flag in a pair. The following has always worked for me

```
  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
```